# API Platform - always apply filter on custom operation

Tags: php, api-platform.com

I have a custom collection operation on my entity (`/api/posts/active`), and I want to always apply a few filtering conditions to it:

1. Fetch only those with `active` = true;
2. Fetch only those with `onlineUntil` > now();

How do I do this ONLY for this specific `collectionOperation`, and not all of them?

Also, how do I implement these filters by default, without dependencies on query strings like `/posts/:id/active?active=true`.

I have read the documentation regarding filtering but I'm really confused as they never mention filtering only a specific operation or applying the filter by default, without the query strings.

Answer (score 1):

I think that filters are not needed here. You could achieve your goal with custom operation (see [custom operation section](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations#creating-custom-operations-and-controllers) in the docs) and [switch off receiving](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations#entity-retrieval) for it. And then, inside the __invoke method get collection of active posts with qustom query from the PostRepository, which could be retrieved there by injecting in the custom operation constructor:

```
public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
{
    $this->em = $em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the typical use case for a custom extension (https://api-platform.com/docs/core/extensions)